# Resize an already-presented modal view controller using formSheet presentation style

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uikit

Before presenting a view controller, we can set the `modalPresentationStyle` to `.formSheet`, and then set a `preferredContentSize` to control the size of the presented modal:

```
let controller = ModalViewController()
controller.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
controller.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
present(controller, animated: true)
```

[image]

Once displayed, is there a way to resize this modal? For example, if the presented view controller is a log in form with an option to create an account instead, the two fields for email and password might expand to collect a first and last name. How do we increase the size of the modal to accommodate them?

I have updated the `preferredContentSize` but it seems to have no effect once the view controller is already presented.

Answer (score 0):

After setting new `preferredContentSize`, call this:

```
if let superView = view.superview?.superview {
    superView.setNeedsLayout()
}
```

How did I find it? I sent the app to the background and entered it again to find that view controller has been set to correct size, then used view hierarchy debugger to have a look at parent views, then some trail and error.

**- Edit:**

More solid implementation:

```
var brokenView = view
while brokenView != nil {
    brokenView?.setNeedsLayout()
    brokenView = brokenView?.superview
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this would work I'm sure but is a little fragile since it relies on the structure of both my own and Apple's view/controller hierarchy. For example, this would be different if navigation controllers and tab bar controllers are involved (or if Apple insert additional views).

Comment: You are right, views hierarchy are different with navigation and tab bar controllers, but it still fixes the problem. Anyway, you could loop through super views to have more solid and future-proof implementation, till they fix it (or is it meant to be like this?).

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used this trick to force the size update:

```swift
self.presentationController?.containerView?.setNeedsLayout()
```

Where (at least in my case) `self.presentationController?.containerView` is the same object (i.e. an instance of `UITransitionView`) as `self.view.superview?.superview`.

---

Note that in case you use the same method to update your preferredContentSize while the viewController is not yet being presented:

Both `self.presentationController?.containerView` and `self.view.superview?.superview` are nil until the viewController is actually being presented, so using optional chaining in the first case should be a safe noop with no unwanted side effects while the viewController is yet not being presented.

In the second case, you would likely want to use `self.viewIfLoaded?.superview?.superview`, so as not to provoke a too early load of the view.